# C++ assigning arrays to eachother; type int* = type int works but not int = int*?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, int, assign

I have a question:

Why does this throw an error (cannot convert from int* to int[5])

```
int static_Array[5]; 
int *dynamic_Array;

dynamic_Array = new int[5];
static_Array = dynamic_Array;
```

while this works fine?

```
int static_Array[5]; 
int *dynamic_Array;

dynamic_Array = new int[5];
dynamic_Array = static_Array; //This line changed
```

I am guessing that types int can be converted to int* by the compiler?
But then why couldn't int be converted to int* by the compiler as well?

Anyone can provide an actual explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: It's because an array can't appear on the left-hand side of an assignment.

Comment: `dynamic_Array = static_Array` doesn't copy the array, it makes the pointer point at the first `int` in the array.

Comment: Because you can't assign a pointer(or something else) to an array, but you can assign an array to a pointer.

Comment: Aah! I was so far off ahaha thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one:

```
int static_Array[5]; 
int *dynamic_Array = new int[5]; // 1.

dynamic_Array = static_Array;    // 2.
```

1. dynamically allocates an array and stores the address of first element in pointer `dynamic_Array`
2. overwrites this address with an address of the first element of the `static_Array`

But this one:

```
int static_Array[5]; 
int *dynamic_Array = new int[5];

static_Array = dynamic_Array;
```

attempts to initialize an array using an address (thus compiler gives error about invalid pointer to array conversion).

*So why the first one works?*
Because static **array** (on the right side) immediately **decays to a pointer**. This can not work the other way, there is no guarantee that this pointer points to an array.

Answer (score 2):

When a raw array is specified in a context where a pointer is expected, it converts to pointer to first item (in the sense of producing that pointer value), which is called a type **decay**.

Contexts where that doesn't happen include `sizeof` expression, `typeid` expression and binding to reference to array.

But essentially that means that raw arrays are not assignable, and of course you cannot assign a pointer to an array variable, for what should the result be.

However, if you put an array in a `struct`, then you can assign the `struct`. And that's what `std::array` is. But when you want an assignable dynamic size array, use `std::vector`.

In passing, there is is also a similar type decay for functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
int static_Array[5];
```

Here static_Array is const pointer to static_Array[0], you cannot modify it like,

```
 static_Array = dynamic_Array;
```

Comment: An array is not a pointer. But in a pointer-like context an array as expression, produces a pointer to first item. Which is called a type decay.